# Excel: I would like to rank values by dates with same dates occurring in multiple rows. Not ranking dates. Ranking values

Tags: excel-formula, rank

[image]

There are 3 columns, Date, Value, Rank.

I manually inputted the Rank, but am working on a formula to do this.

I understand and can easily work with the Excel rank function, but don't know how to do this when trying to separately rank by date.
Please let me know if there is a formula available that I could drag down to fill the rank of values (highest with the number 1, 2nd highest with the number 2, 3rd highest with the number 3, etc) by each separate date.  I have not been able to discover a formula that would allow me to drag it down and fill in the rank by date.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Referring to the attached image, assuming that the "Date" cell located at `A1`, the solution would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15, A2, $B$2:$B$15, ">"&B2)+1
```

Dragging this formula down from `C2` to `C15` would produce the same results that I manually entered.